# Correct way to express monetary loss (dollar vs. dollars)

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural, numbers

Which of these is correct?

> Six million dollar loss
>
> Six million dollar**s** loss

My guess would be the first one based on a web site ([acapela-box](https://www.acapela-box.com/AcaBox/index.php)).

Comment: Why do you think that it might be the second?

Comment: I don't think that it might be the second. I think that it might be the first. Am I wrong?

Comment: Ah! Sorry. I thought that your capital S was a dollar sign ($). I need new glasses. Both are correct although the first is, perhaps, idiomatic.

Comment: It's spoken like a unit: "dollar". Examples using other units: one kilometer stretch, two mile hike, three second interval.

Comment: @MickSharpe Thanks. I just want to put emphasis on the existence of the letter S.

Comment: @Lawrence Thanks for your clear explanation. Those examples expand my knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first is correct.

In your example phrase, *loss* is the noun, and *dollar* is an adjective describing "what kind" of loss.

Only nouns and verbs have plural forms in English.  Adjectives always stay the same.

This is why if you said "a loss of six million dollars" - you do add the *s*, because now *dollars* is a noun.

Answer (score 0):

It should be singular: "dollar." And it should probably be hyphenated for better readability: "six-million-dollar loss"? Similar to "I have a two-year-old son" or "seven-year itch"? The Chicago Manual of Style recommends hyphenating when the unit (dollar in this case) is spelled out (not abbreviated, like lb or cm) unless the unit is "percent." In regards to money in particular, this also applies to indefinite amounts like "multimillion-dollar loss."